# type or namespace InterpolationMode not found

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have a .net application and now I am trying to build it to mobile application but I am getting an error as:

> "type or namespace InterpolationMode not found"

But I have included all references,

- using System.Drawing;
- using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
- using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Please let me know what I have to include?

Answer (score 1):

InterpolationMode is not supported in the Compact Framework (nor are any method overloads that accept it, so adding it would be of no use).  Without seeing how you're using it, it's very difficult to recommend a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Include namespace - using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

Also see - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's System.Drawing.dll according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx). Maybe mobile SDK doesn't include it? I'm not sure

Comment: I have include System.Drawing.dll